# cant work out how to do "chkconfig systat on" & "service systat start" on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: command-line, apt

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Ubutu from command line?  We have no GUI.

## chkconfig sysstat on

## service sysstat start

I tried installing chkconfig, and get the error:

"Package chkconfig is not available, but is referred to by another package...
E: Package 'chkconfig' has no installation candidate"

I saw someone said you have to use "sysv-rc-conf", but this command:

## apt-get install sysv-rc-conf

Gives exactly the same install error as chkconfig.

Someone else suggested using upstart, but this looks very complex and I could not work out how to use it on to do the above 2 commands.

I also saw someone recommending "update-rc.d".  I have looked at this page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

But unfortunately am still clueless how this tool can be used to do the simple automatic starting of a service.

In the old days we would simple edit rc2.d scripts, is this still possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysstat is still a init script, not changed to upstart yet. If you have installed it it will normally autostart.

To check if it is running you can use:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sysstat status
```

and to manually start:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sysstat start
```

I do not know where you got the instruction to start it using upstart (which will be the new way for handling start scripts but currently both init.d (the old fashion rc scripts) and upstart are used next to each other.

PS. For sysstat to run it should be enabled in the file `/etc/default/sysstat`.